# System.NullException and other errors - disable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to remove or disable these errors? Ie, that they would not be displayed, but the application was simply closed.
Is this possible?
Example error:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIQci.jpg)

Comment: How about fixing the application so that it crash?

Comment: Sure, use a try/catch or fix the exceptions.

Comment: @Amy beat me by 7 seconds.

Comment: @DourHighArch Given how they asked this question, I don't think it's a duplicate. The OP doesn't want to fix the `NullReferenceException`, they just want to close the application when one is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to wrap the code that is generating this exception in a `try...catch` block and close the application in the `catch`.

See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/exception-handling) for more information about handling exceptions in .NET.